# encoding base64 in C# decoding in Java

Tags: c#, java, xml, base64, document

Please help 
I am having problem with correct encoding Clinical Document to base 64 and sending it to the Document object.
Here is code I am using.

1.step I am encoding PDF file to Base64

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pdffile); 
return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

This string attached to Clinical documet

2.Attaching CDA document to Metadata submission request

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(CDADocument.xml);
string ReturnValue = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
byte[] newbyte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ReturnValue);

doc[0].Value = newbyte;
```

Submission request passes all steps but decoding is not working.
They are using Java API to decode the submission request.
Thank you for your help

Comment: What is a *Clinical Document*?

Comment: Obvious question... if `.Value` is `byte[]`, why not just give it `bytes` instead of base-64 and utf-8?

Comment: I can not use bytes because I have to encode to base64 first.Base64 returs string but value parameter expects Byte

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the options for both are the same.

For example, C# will pad by default, with '='. Java may not be expecting it to be padded.

There may be other incompatible options, like adding new line on end, or in the middle to split on to multi-lines, but padding is the most obvious one I would say.

Comment: Thank you I don't have access to decoding programm.Is it possible to put some code to match with Java decoding.How I would know if pad ornew lines are different.

Comment: thank you very much for this comment, I am new in C#. Is there any code to match encoding and decoding between C# and Java?

Comment: Sorry I don't have anything, the only java I do is android.Did they give you a spec that specified UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

I am using base64 to pass data from asp.net c# server code to java applet and there are no problems. 
The only problem that you may have here is the UTF8 part.
UTF8 (or any other encoding) must be used by both parties while encoding and decoding.